# add a column to dataFrame from another dataFrame

Tags: r

I have a data frame allData that has 3 columns,and a data frame userData with 1 column.that every row of all data refers to a row of user data.

now I want to add userData column to my allData data frame.but I cant.

I tried some codes Like :

```
allData$user <- userData$userId
```

or:

```
cbind(allData , userData)
```

but non of theme do not work correctly.they produce a data with lots of columns unexpectedly.

how can I add user column to my allData data frame?

thank you.

Comment: You can start by creating a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am new in R.I think I asked my question in form of android questions.excuse me for wasting your time.

Comment: Your question should include at least types of objects or their `str(x)` output in order for us to help you better. Without this information we can only guess what structures you're using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By guessing what you want, here is a possible code

```
> allData <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,0), y=c(2,1,0), z=c(5,2,5))
> userData <- data.frame(userId=c(1,2,5))

> allData <- cbind(allData, userID = userData$userId)

> allData
  x y z userID
1 1 2 5      1
2 1 1 2      2
3 0 0 5      5
```

Comment: I dont know what was the difference between this and what I tried.but It works.thank you